# Getting an error testing Heroes tutorial code

Tags: aqueduct

I'm working through the generic Heroes tutorial, and have come to the section on testing. I run the basic included test and it throws an error `[SEVERE] aqueduct: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast Instance of 'Application<HeroesChannel>'`. Suggestions are greatly appreciated.